# Right and left inverse in $X^X=\{f:X\to X\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

The monoid of all the functions $X^X=\{f:X\to X\}$ has a right inverse : the the surjective function and a left inverse: the injective function.

I remember that it has to do with the set theory, is there a simple and intuition explanation?

Comment: What do you mean by the right-inverse of a set?

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is that elements of the monoid will have a right-inverse iff they are surjective, and a left-inverse iff they are injective.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It happens that complete answers are already available, although they are somewhat scattered, especially in "proof verification" problems. This is an attempt to make something a little more canonical. If it happens that there is a more canonical version that I missed in my search, we should link this question as a duplicate to that. Alternatively someone with a gold badge could link the entire collection of questions I'm going to list.*

---

If a function $f:X\to Y$ is surjective, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/440832/29335) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3048616/29335)

If a function $f:X\to Y$ is injective, then 
see [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1075924/29335).

Proving the converses of both statements is easy to do directly and is done in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165434/29335).